# Firefox bookmarks in KRunner on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, krunner

After clean install of Kubuntu 17.04 KRunner can't see Firefox bookmarks. I have tried unchecking/checking Bookmarks plugin in Search Settings but it didn't solve the problem. How can I get bookmarks search back?

I use Firefox 55.0.2, KDE Plasma 5.9.5, KDE Frameworks 5.31.0

Comment: Krunner obtains the bookmarks from Konqueror, not Firefox.

Comment: @MichaelBay wouldn't that be Dolphin rather than Konqueror, at least in a default vanilla Kubuntu 17.04?

Comment: @MichaelBay I could access Firefox boomarks in KRunner on Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @MichaelBay I have tested Kubuntu 17.04 live USB - I can access Firefox bookmarks in KRunner there. I assume that this feature should work.